# Problem regarding changing bounds of summation

Tags: calculus, summation

We have the following expression:
$$
A(x) = f'\sum_{c=1}^{n-1} \sum_{k=c+1}^n \sum_{j_1} \Phi(k,c,j) f^{k-c-j}g^{c-j} \sum_{l=1}^{n-1} {n \choose l}\rho(f,n-l,c-1)\rho(g,l,k-c) + g'\sum_{c=1}^{n-1} \sum_{k=c+1}^n \sum_{j_2} \Phi(k,c,j) f^{k-c-j}g^{c-j} \sum_{l=1}^{n-1} {n \choose l} \rho(f,n-l,c)\rho(g,l,k-c-1)
$$
The sums $j_1$ and $j_2$ are at the moment the same summation (so I will represent there bounds as the variable $j$). They are defined by the following inequality:
$$
k-c \ge j \ge 0 \quad \quad \quad (k-c \le c)
$$
and
$$
c \ge j \ge 0 \quad\quad\quad (c \le k-c)
$$
Now i am trying to get the $l$ summation into the following form:
$$
\sigma(f,g,n,k,c) = \sum_{l=1}^{n-1} {n \choose l} \rho(f,n-l,c)\rho(g,l,k-c)
$$
Now i will show you how I accomplished this:
\begin{align*}
f'\sum_{c=1}^{n-1} \sum_{k=c+1}^n \sum_{j_1} \Phi(k,c,j) f^{k-c-j}g^{c-j} \sum_{l=1}^{n-1} {n \choose l}\rho(f,n-l,c-1)\rho(g,l,k-c)
\\
 = f'\sum_{c=0}^{n-2} \sum_{k=c+2}^n \sum_{j_1} \Phi(k,c+1,j) f^{k-c-j-1}g^{c-j+1} \sum_{l=1}^{n-1} {n \choose l}\rho(f,n-l,c)\rho(g,l,k-c-1)
\\
 = f'g\sum_{c=0}^{n-2} \sum_{k=c+1}^{n-1} \sum_{j_1} \Phi(k+1,c+1,j) f^{k-c-j}g^{c-j} \sigma(f,g,n,k,c)
\end{align*}
Now for the other summation:
\begin{align*}
g'\sum_{c=1}^{n-1} \sum_{k=c+1}^n \sum_{j_2} \Phi(k,c,j) f^{k-c-j}g^{c-j} \sum_{l=1}^{n-1} {n \choose l} \rho(f,n-l,c)\rho(g,l,k-c-1)
\\
=g'f\sum_{c=1}^{n-1} \sum_{k=c}^{n-1} \sum_{j_2}\Phi(k+1,c,j) f^{k-c-j}g^{c-j} \sigma(f,g,n,k,c)
\end{align*}
This is swell and all, but there is one problem with what I have done. I have no idea how to implement these boundary changed on my $j_1$ and $j_2$ summations. Can someone please explain how this can be done?

Comment: Is it wrong to just have $$\sum_{j_i=0}^a$$ for each $j_i$ where $a=\min\{c,k-c\}$?

Comment: @AdinaGoldberg Well this is new for me, Is this method of expressing the bounds of $j$ easy to manipulate with what I have done?

Comment: It seems that the only summation you move is the summation over $l$, which has no relationship to the bounds on the $j_i$ summations. So it seems nothing should change about the bounds on the $j_i$.

Comment: @AdinaGoldberg Well since the sum $j$ is relying on the values of $c$ and $k$ and since i shifted them over one, wouldn't that result in the some sort of difference with the $j$ bounds?

Comment: Just note that $a$ is a function of $c$ and $k$, so it will change as $c$ and $k$ vary. Perhaps it would be good to write it as $a(c,k)$ instead to explicitly note the dependence.

Comment: Oh I see, let me look more closely at that.

Comment: Two comments:
1) When you manipulated the first summation, why did the bounds on the $k$ sum go from $c+1, n$ to $c+2, n$ (i.e., the upper bound didn't change)?
2) You know how when you add 1 to the bounds on a sum, you must subtract 1 from the variable inside the expression? (And vice versa?) It's the same for $a$. If you increase $c$ by $1$, you must use $a(c-1,k)$ as a bound instead. Etc.

Comment: @AdinaGoldberg i manipulated the bounds on $c$ which in turn i shifted every value on the $c$ bounds -1, since the $k$ summation is dependant on $c$, the shift affected that $c$ as well. for example:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{l=k}^m f(k,l) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \sum_{l=k+1}^m f(k+1,l)
$$
Which is why i was worried about the $j$ summation, it is dependant on both $c$ and $k$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like for the $j_1$ sum you want the upper bound to be $a(c+1,k+1)$ and for the $j_2$ sum you want the upper bound to be $a(c,k+1)$, where $a(c,k) = \min\{c,k-c\}$.